# Why can't I manually add this VMware based machine?

Tags: vmware, maas

[GUI "add machine dialog"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPeb3.png)

Using VMware fusion 11 pro, I've created a rack controller. It correctly provides PXEboot to a raw machine; but enlistment failed. To make progress, it seemed that "add machine" ought to be easy enough. But filling in all the required fields does NOT ungrey "save machine" is one of the optional fields required? Or is there some way to elicit a useful error?

Comment: I think perhaps this is better suited to [VMWare Community Forms](https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/developer/forums)

Answer (score 0):

Curiouser and curiouser. Changing the login credentials did get to "save" but aren't working (and considering there isn't a guest OS yet, I was obviously misled. On the host mac,

```
vmrun start  Virtual\ Machines.localized/Clonemaas_slave1.vmwarevm
```

started the machine (so VMware isn't imposing the requirement for credentials). The machine makes it to "new" but fails commissioning with

Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The other settings:
vm UUID (cd $VMs/grep -Ri ...) but also deleted the UUID and used the name

vmware hostname: localhost
username:        $myMacUserName
vmware password: $myMacLogin

note ssh $myMacUserName@localhost works fine.